# rails win7 aptana debug server fail to start

Tags: ruby-on-rails, windows, debugging, aptana, rmagick

i have the following installed for my rails app on windows 7.

windows 7 64bit
ruby 1.8.7
rails 2.3.14
activesupport 2.3.9, 2.3.14
bundler 1.0.21
carrierwave 0.4.10
polyglot 0.3.2
rmagick 2.13.1
ruby-debug-base 0.10.4
ruby-debug-ide 0.4.16

gemfile
gem "activesupport", "~> 2.3.9"
gem "bundler", "1.0.21"
gem "carrierwave", "0.4.10"
gem "polyglot", "0.3.2"
gem "rails", "2.3.14"
gem "rmagick", "2.13.1"
gem "ruby-debug-base", "0.10.4"
gem "ruby-debug-ide", "0.4.16"

imagemagick installed at C:\ImageMagick-6.7.3-Q16

when i started 'Debug Server' in aptana studio 3, the following errors returned and the server could not be started. if i started 'Run server', everything started successfully.

Polyglot: found more than one candidate for RMagick2.so:
c:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rmagick-2.13.1/lib/RMagick2.so, c:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rmagick-2.13.1/lib/RMagick2.so.

RMagick2.so was detected two times.

1. what am i doing wrong?
2. how can i fix it?

   Fast Debugger (ruby-debug-ide 0.4.16, ruby-debug-base 0.10.4) listens on 127.0.0.1:52876
   => Booting Mongrel
   => Rails 2.3.14 application starting on http://0.0.0.0:3000
   NOTE: Gem.source_index is deprecated, use Specification. It will be removed on or after 2011-11-01.
   Gem.source_index called from c:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.14/lib/rails/gem_dependency.rb:21.
   Polyglot: found more than one candidate for RMagick2.so: c:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rmagick-2.13.1/lib/RMagick2.so, c:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rmagick-2.13.1/lib/RMagick2.so.
       c:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rmagick-2.13.1/lib/RMagick2.so
       c:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/polyglot-0.3.2/lib/polyglot.rb:63:in `require'

       c:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.14/lib/active_support  /dependencies.rb:182:in`require'
       c:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.14/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:547:in `new_constants_in'

       c:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.14/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:182:in`require'
       c:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rmagick-2.13.1/lib/rmagick.rb:11
       c:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.21/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:68:in `require'

       c:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.21/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:68:in`require'
       c:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.21/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:66:in `each'

       c:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.21/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:66:in`require'
       c:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.21/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:55:in `each'

       c:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.21/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:55:in`require'
       c:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.21/lib/bundler.rb:122:in `require'

       C:/Ruby/work/whistle/config/boot.rb:117:in`load_gems'
       c:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.14/lib/initializer.rb:164:in `process'

       c:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.14/lib/initializer.rb:113:in`send'
       c:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.14/lib/initializer.rb:113:in `run'

       C:/Ruby/work/whistle/config/environment.rb:10

       c:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.14/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:182:in`require'
       c:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.14/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:182:in `require'

       c:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.14/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:547:in`new_constants_in'
       c:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.14/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:182:in `require'

       c:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.14/lib/commands/server.rb:84

       C:\Ruby\work\whistle\script\server:3:in`require'
       C:\Ruby\work\whistle\script\server:3
       c:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/ruby-debug-ide-0.4.16/lib/ruby-debug-ide.rb:112:in `debug_load'

       c:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/ruby-debug-ide-0.4.16/lib/ruby-debug-ide.rb:112:in`debug_program'
       c:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/ruby-debug-ide-0.4.16/bin/rdebug-ide:87
       c:/Ruby/bin/rdebug-ide:19:in `load'
       c:/Ruby/bin/rdebug-ide:19
   Uncaught exception: 126: �䤣���w���ҲաC   - c:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rmagick-2.13.1/lib/RMagick2.so

batterhead

Answer (score 0):

Try to run both `bundle install` and `bundle update`